# how to hide windows host script c#.net

Tags: c#, cmd

I need hide hide Windows host script after this code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C slmgr.vbs /dlv";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about just hiding the window completely then you are missing setting the `CreateNoWindow` property.

```
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

Instead of firing up an additional command-prompt, use *cscript.exe* to execute your VB script. If you do it this way you won't have to worry about the shell figuring out how to execute you vbs file and you won't get an additional command-line window.

```
startInfo.FileName = "cscript.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "slmgr.vbs /dlv";
```

If the executable that is creating this process is not in the same directory as slmgr.vbs, you'll also need to set the full path to the file in the arguments, or set the working directory that the process runs in.

```
// Example path where your scripts could reside.
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\PathToMyScripts\VBScripts\";
```

You probably want to [redirect the output](http://www.dotnetperls.com/redirectstandardoutput) as well so you can log it somewhere.

Comment: Thank You But if i add another command like slmgr /ipk GCRJD-8NW9H-F2CDX-CCM8D-9D6T9    not work

Comment: Is it not because you are missing the '.vbs' from you second command?

Comment: @AhmedMagdi: Updated the answer to include setting the working directory in case that is the reason you command is not working. Also remember to include the '.vbs' extension when passing it as an argument.

Comment: mr BrutalDev thank you but i try and not work can you give me the full code

Comment: @AhmedMagdi: You already have all the code you need, just copy the code from the answer and replace yours. If it is not working try be more specific as to what the error actually is or even if it throws an exception.

Comment: hello my friend the cscript not entered the key in cmd

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for mr.BrutalDev
the second step 
change `startInfo.Arguments = "slmgr.vbs /dlv";`
to `startInfoent.Arguments = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\slmgr.vbs /dlv";`